# How to pull data by looping over dates in pyspark sql?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a script where I'm pulling data into a pyspark DataFrame using spark sql. The script is shown below:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

df_query = """
select 
  *
from schema.table
where start_date between date '2019-03-01' and date '2019-03-07'
"""
df = spark.sql(df_query)
```

Currently, the script pulls data for a particular week. However, I want to iterate this script over all weeks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) class for that:

```py
import datetime

startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
maxDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-04-03', "%Y-%m-%d")


while startDate <= maxDate:
    endDate = startDate + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

    df_query = """
select 
  *
from schema.table
where start_date between date '{}' and date '{}'
""".format(startDate.date(), endDate.date())
    print(df_query)
    startDate = endDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```